How to align canvas to center of button?
How would I center a canvas on a button?


const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 150, 100);
<button>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>. 
</button>




You understand your rectangle is bigger than the size of your canvas ? Your canvas is 100px large, your rectangle is 150px ?

Your canvas is already centered. The rect is not centered because you're setting an offset of 20, 20. Try ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);


const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
<button>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas> 
</button>



